# Using Placeholder Settings on default SXA Accordion

Tags: sxa, placeholders, dynamic-placeholder

Did someone manage to use proper placeholder settings for these sxa composite components? I am asking because of the accordion, I want to limit the usage to specific components that can be placed into an accordion item.
The placeholders look like "/main/section-content-1-2"
There is a chapter about known limitations for dynamic placeholders, that clearly states that placeholder settings will only work with the initial key:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-management/en/dynamic-placeholders.html

So did someone already found a nice workaround for that?

Regards

Comment: We are using sitecore 8.2 and recently added SXA sites. The existing site has a dynamic placeholder setting "section-content*", which stopped working after we added SXA sites. When I looked for "section-content" in website folder, I see some placeholders "@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("section-content")" added as part of SXA installation. I have realized there is a name conflict and that's the reason components do not save on this placeholder in the existing site. If I decide to rename the SXA PH, I don't understand the impact it might have. I need your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The article you've mentioned is for platform Dynamic Placeholders. SXA is not using them, we have our own version.

Try creating placeholder settings item with the following key: `section-content-*` (or `section-content*`). The `*` is to make a placeholder dynamic and guarantee a uniqueness to the placeholder key across different renderings.